# MathTime Pro 2 [lite] doesn't change \sin function font

Tags: fonts, xepersian, mtpro

I am writing bidirectional Persian+English text using `xepersian` and for math mode i try to use MathTime Pro 2 lite version BUT:

1. It doesn't change `\sin, \cos` function font (it uses `LMRoman` for this functions).
2. When I uncomment lines 3,4; then `\PARENS{}` defined by `mtpro2` package doesn't work (instead of `\PARENS{}` `-->` `\left( \right)` works)

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}
   \usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

   %\usepackage{xepersian}
   %\settextfont{B Nazanin}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{equation}
   \PARENS{
   \begin{array}{c}
       \sin x \\
        y \\
       \cos z \\
       \sin x \\
        y \\
      \cos z \\
   \end{array} }
   \end{equation}
   \end{document}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As it is advertised, `mtpro2` is only a *math font*. You need to specify a Times text font, e.g., `newtxtext`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{B Nazanin}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\PARENS{
\begin{array}{c}
    \sin x \\
     y \\
    \cos z \\
    \sin x \\
     y \\
   \cos z \\
\end{array} }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Times text and math]